# Create a plugin to connect PostgreSQL db and run a query using QGIS Plugin

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt

I have prepared a code to connect PostgreSQL database and run a query on the database using PyQGIS and it is running successfully on python console of QGIS. I want the same to happen using QGIS Python Plugin.
How can I write that in a Python Plugin File or inside which method shall I write the same.

Comment: I suggest you to look at Plugin Builder under QGIS or the command line tool [Plugin builder tool](http://g-sherman.github.io/plugin_build_tool/).